# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and the cone.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

The projection $\pi(x,y,z) = (x,y)$ defines a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $C = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid x^{2} + y^{2} 
 - z = 0, z \geq 0\}$. This is the classic approach to show that the cone and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ are homeomorphic. My question is just curiosity:

> - Is there a more elegant way to show this homeomorphism? I mean, without having to check each condition, maybe using some stronger result.

---

**Edit.** I know that the projection give a simple proof. I wanted to know if this homeomorphism can be obtained as a consequence of some stronger result, without the need to use an explicit function.

Comment: I think that the projection is about as simple as it gets. Why do you find it not to be elegant? I think it's quite neat.

Comment: Your definition of $C$ does not really make sense. It's just a singleton of the origin.

Comment: @tomasz Its a typo

Comment: @LucasCorrêa: It still doesn't make sense, but in a different way: the equation already implies that $z$ is non-negative.

Comment: @tomasz it would be the cone in the above $xy$ plane. I dont know if I understand the problem.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa: Yes, what I mean is that the $z\geq 0$ part is redundant.

Comment: I see. I've seen some definitions taking $z>0$ so I explained, but I really see that it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

It as an obvious inverse: $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,-x^2-y^2)$. Furthermore, this functions is clearly continuous. How more elegant than this can you get?

Comment: I expressed myself badly. I meant, a proof without the need to verify that a given function satisfies the conditions of homeomorphism. This is the only proof I know of. I just wish I had some other, just out of curiosity.